# do 'mongotemlate save' not use getter in object?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "myCollection")
public class MyObject{

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String articleName;
    private Writer writer;
    

    public Writer getWriter() {
        if (this.writer == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(this.writer.getNickName())) {
            return null;
        }
        return writer;
    }
 }
```

it is my class. When i save this object,  I expected there is an object with writer is null because writer.nickname is null..but writer is not null

umm.. sorry for my eng ..

My real question is that 'do mongotemlate not use getter in object?' .

I think 'mongotemplate save' don't use getter when save.
is It true?

mongodb version: 4.2.14
spring boot version: 1.5.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `@AccessType(Type.PROPERTY)` on above of your **getWriter** method.

When you create a class and not set any **AccessType** then by default it will select `@AccessType(Type.FIELD)`.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "myCollection")
public class MyObject{

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String articleName;
    private Writer writer;
    
    @AccessType(Type.PROPERTY)
    public Writer getWriter() {
        if (this.writer == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(this.writer.getNickName())) {
            return null;
        }
        return writer;
    }
 }
```

[Access Type Enum](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/AccessType.html)

So it does not depend on the mongo template it depends on how you use spring persistent properties.